# review of permission to publish_actions is rejected

Tags: facebook, publish-actions

I get the following rejection when I try to get publish_actions rights for my appication:

People must enter all content in the user message field. Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content, including links and hashtags, even if you allow users to edit the content before sharing.
Please remove any pre-filled text from your shared content before resubmitting for review.
You can find more detail and examples in this informational video, and in Platform Policy 2.3

But my application (website) does not add any content to the facebook post, that the user has not selected.

My first question is:

**Is my application being rejected because I'm converting a category-selection in my application (f.ex "Cars") to a hash tag (f.ex #Cars) in the facebook post?**

My second question is:

**If my application allows the user to enter a price (f.ex 100 dollars) in a separate field, am I not allowed to add the string "100 dollars" to the facebook post?**

Toby

Answer (score 0):

As stated in their policy,People must enter all content in the user message field. Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content.

That means you cant add any hash tags or string (in your case - 100 dollars) in the message content.